Icon meanings in Android Auto for Nissan Rogue
I have an Android Auto for the Nissan Rogue. Does anyone know what these different icons mean?

The little phones are calls, but there is a different one-rectangle cell phone looking. Is that video chat? I couldn't find pictures anywhere sorry!

Without knowing anything about Nissan systems my guess would be that these are quick dial icons, each of one contact or phone number. Based on the telephone number type (normal or mobile) you get a different icon.
